# How to make a function with independently changing variables?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function make some objects move randomly around the screen. I would like to make each of them move independently of one another. However, I would like to not have to make a new global variable every time I call the function. But, if I define the variables within the function, I am unable to use += to increase the values because every time the function loops it just resets the variable. I can get around this by creating a new global variable for every time I want to call the function again, But that gets really messy. Is there any way to avoid this? Perhaps with a global array variable that's length is increased every time I call the function?

```
    //First Situation

    var exampleFunction = function(x){

        fill(0,0,0)
        ellipse(x, 200, 50, 50);
        x += 1;

        if(x > 400 || x < 0) {
            x = 200;
        }

    }

    draw = function(){
        background(255, 255, 255);
        exampleFunction(200);
        exampleFunction(300);
    }

    //this doesn't work because the value of "x" is reset every time the                 
    //function loops and the value stays at x + 1, so the ellipses don't     
    //move

    //Second Situation
                                               |
    //i tried to make an global array variable like this  V

    var x = [];

    //Then I would add another value to this variable every time I called     
    //the function. But the problem was that every time I called the 
    //function i need to define a new value in the variable. so I'd do 
    //something like this 

    var x = [];

    var exampleFunction = function(num){

        x[num] = 1;
        x[num] += 1;

        fill(0, 0, 0);
        ellipse(x[num], 200, 50, 50);
        x += 1;

        if(x > 400 || x < 0) {
            x = 200;
        }
    }

    draw = function(){
        background(255, 255, 255);
        exampleFunction(1);
        exampleFunction(2);
    }
```

But this had the same problem of resetting every time I ran the function, so I needed some way to define the variable the first time I ran the function and then not again. But I couldn't figure out anyway to do this. I don't know if there is some command I'm missing, or if it's just not possible. Please help.

question here, so please forgive me for any formatting errors ;)

I don't know if I'm missing something obvious or what. The purpose of the function, originally, was to have some characters wander back and forth along the bottom of the screen which would change directions anytime they hit a wall. I wanted them to all behave independently of one another, but to call them all with one function. I couldn't figure out how.

Also I'm just writing this code now to explain, so there might be syntax errors in it.

Okay Heres a link to an example of what I mean: https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-of-project-shooting-star/6194034937331712

^
|
If you look at this code, I have to make a global variable for everyone of the bubbles. Is there any way I can do this with just a function without the global extra variables.

Comment: You talk about "function loops" but your code doesn't show anything about it, there's function calls that don't need to be in the snippets (like background()).... Also, please, think about less text in your question, it will be better if you focus on what code you have and what is the expected result... And, there's many errors in the code (like incrementing an array `x += 1`

Comment: It will be easier to read the question and help you if you adjust those things in the question. a [mcve] would be great

Comment: In the lines 8 to 12 from the end, your are incrementing `x` which is an array. Also you are checking if `x > 400 || x < 0`. Isn't that wrong?

Comment: Use a constructor or a class.

Comment: I feel like this would be a great candidate for a generator function. you could do a loop to initialize `n` generator functions for `n` number of desired objects. just save the generators into an array and loop over it however you like. docs for generators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2A

Comment: I added a link in my question to some code that shows my problem

Answer (score 1):

Simply set variable inside function by let (not var):

```
var exampleFunction = function(x){
        let counter = x;

        fill(0,0,0)
        ellipse(counter, 200, 50, 50);
        counter += 1;

        if(counter > 400 || counter < 0) {
            counter = 200;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What difference does it make whether it uses `var` or `let`? Both of them create local variables, so it won't remember the value between calls.

Comment: I tried that, it has the same problem. The object doesn't move.